# Android set color

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

How is it possible to set backgroundcolor from dialog(SettingsFColorDialod) to activity? There is one activity with fragment, one of the fragment's button opens dialog and there are some buttons for change color in sharedpreferences. It works but only when activity is reloaded.

My dialog is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.AppData.FCOLOR_KEY;
import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.AppData.TRANSP_KEY;
import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.AppData.editordata;
import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.AppData.prefdata;
// ...

public class SettingsFColorDialod extends DialogFragment {


    public SettingsFColorDialod() {
    }

    public static SettingsFColorDialod newInstance(String title) {
        SettingsFColorDialod frag = new SettingsFColorDialod();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("Choose your color", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingsfcolordialog, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        prefdata = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editordata = prefdata.edit();

        view.findViewById(R.id.FCOLOR1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editordata.putString(FCOLOR_KEY,"FF9999").apply();
                changecolors();
                dismiss();
            }
        });




        String title = getArguments().getString("Choose your color", "Choose your color");
        getDialog().setTitle(title);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    }

    private void changecolors(){
        prefdata = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        getView().findViewById(R.id.mainavatarbck).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(prefdata.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + prefdata.getString(FCOLOR_KEY, "33777F")));
        getView().findViewById(R.id.mainnamebck).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(prefdata.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + prefdata.getString(FCOLOR_KEY, "33777F")));

    }
}
```

Problem is in "changecolors",I tried create this method for change backgroundcolors without refresh but there is error (unfortunately application has stopped), and from android monitor:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40, PID: 22743
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.SettingsFColorDialod.changecolors(SettingsFColorDialod.java:176)
                                                                              at com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.SettingsFColorDialod.access$000(SettingsFColorDialod.java:23)
                                                                              at com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.SettingsFColorDialod$16.onClick(SettingsFColorDialod.java:159)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In which file are you calling changecolor()?

Comment: `mainavatarbck` and `mainnamebck` are Textview or LinearLayouts ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya mainavaterbck and mainnamebck are LinearLayouts in MainActivity

Comment: I think u need to store your inflated layout in a View. Use that view during `findViewById`.

Answer (score 0):

If the crash is happening on the first line of `changecolors()` it is probably because `this.getActivity()` is returning null.

Make sure you call `getActivity()` in or after `onAttach()`, or else it will return null.  The `fragment` hasn't associated itself with the activity yet.

Comment: You are right, problem is in this line: getView().findViewById(R.id.mainavatarbck).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(prefdata.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + prefdata.getString(FCOLOR_KEY, "33777F")));  Where should I use onAttach()?

Comment: @Aditya I use it in Dialog, not in fragment (but dialog is open by click button in fragment)

Answer (score 0):

`R.id.mainavatarbck` and `R.id.mainnamebck` are not found in your fragment's layout, that is why `getView().findViewById()` returns null. Try this -

Based on your question, I'm assuming that the views with these 2 ID's are a part of your activity's layout. Change the code in your `changecolors()` method to -

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainavatarbck)...
```